# How to fetch the name of the active menu?

Tags: functions, menus

I have two menu locations. Here is the code:

```
$locations = array( 
        'topprimary' => __( 'Primary nav', 'mytheme' ), 
        'sidebarsecondary' => __( 'Secondary nav', 'mytheme' ) 
);
register_nav_menus( $locations );
```

I want to know how can I get the name of the active menu. I am trying this but it does not work is it the right way or not:

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu );
```

**Update:**

**What I want:**

I want if suppose I have checked the Primary nav. So I want to fetch the name of the topprimary.